# node.js получаю неверный ответ на запрос get

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Клиент шлет запрос получить весь список, вместо списка или ошибки получаю ответ:

```
Object {data: "<!DOCTYPE html>
↵<html lang="en" class="no-js">
↵<…
↵<!--</div>-->
↵<!--</div>-->
↵<!--</div>-->
↵
↵", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
```

серверная сторона:

```
//Find all orders by username
    app.get('/api/orders', function (req, res) {
        //пробовал и тут брейкпоинт, дебагет тут не проходит.
        authorize(req).then(function (foundUser) {
            db.orders.findAll({where: {userId: foundUser.id}})
                .then(function (orders) {
                    res.json({message: 'OKk', body: orders});
                });
        }), function (err) {
            res.status(200).send('User not found');
        }
    });
```

В этом же контроллере есть метод создать заказ

```
//Add new order
    app.post('/api/order', function (req, res) {
        authorize(req).then(function (foundUser) {
            var newOrder = {};
            newOrder.startDate = req.body.startDate;
            newOrder.stopDate = req.body.stopDate;
            newOrder.price = 1;
            newOrder.totalPrice = 100;
            newOrder.userId = foundUser.id;
            db.orders.create(newOrder).then(function (order) {
                db.orders.findAll({where: {userId: foundUser.id}})
                    .then(function (orders) {
                        var ordersList = [];
                        orders.forEach(function (item, i, arr) {
                            var order = {};
                            order.id = item['id'];
                            order.startDate = item['startDate'];
                            order.stopDate = item['stopDate'];
                            order.price = item['price'];
                            order.totalPrice = item['totalPrice'];
                            ordersList.push(order);
                        })
                        res.json({message: 'order added', body: ordersList});
                    });
            });
        }), function (err) {
            res.status(200).send('User not found');
        }
    })
```

Метод работает, и новый заказ создается и потом получаю все заказы.
В чем может быть проблема?

Полный вид контроллера [OrderController.js](https://pastebin.com/GE5870FH)

---

Запрос клиента:

```
$scope.url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/';
$scope.getAllOrders = function () {
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: $scope.url + 'orders',
                }).then(function success(res) {
                    if (res.data.message == 'OK') {
                        $scope.orders = res.data.body;
                    }
                })
            }
```

---

Добавление:

Я попробовал обращаться к несуществующему пути

```
$scope.getAllOrders = function () {
                    $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: $scope.url + 'ordersghjkhg',
```

И получаю тот же ответ от сервера, значит скорее всего проблема в главном файле [server.js](https://pastebin.com/btwpawMM)

После того как я закомментировал в server.js

```
 app.get('*', function (req,res) {
     res.render('./index.html');
 });
```

Метод GET стал обращаться к нужному методу app.get('/api/orders но закомментированный марштур (или я не знаю как его точно назвать) мне нужен что бы корректно работал Angular ui-router, без него любые страницы кроме index при перезагрузке возвращают 404.

Comment: код отправки запроса на сервер можно? Он у вас должен явно быть типа `axios.get('/api/orders').then(fn())`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Добавил наверх.

Comment: объявление дефолтного ответа от сервера можно? у вас с виду все нормально, но кто-то перекрывает ваш метод. Проще весь файл на какой-нибудь pastebin залейте.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Что за дефолтный ответ от сервера? https://pastebin.com/GE5870FH

Comment: Я от вас хотел получить корневой распределитель в index, или где он у вас находится. Там где к примеру `app.get('*', fn())` - это основной разделитель и именно он перехватывает вызов и он должен быть в самом конце, самым последним в роутинге, иначе он может перекрыть методы

Comment: Да так и есть, код исполняется сверху вниз, он выполняется раньше других правил. Догадался по дороге на работу, но протестирую только вечером, тогда отпишусь о результатах.

Comment: Проблема была именно в этом.

Comment: Прекрасно :) удачного коддинга!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод основного роутинга должен находиться самым последним в роутинге, иначе он перекроет определенные выше роуты.

Удачного коддинга!